# Securing an HTML Form before processing by PHP.

Tags: php, forms, security

I have created a PHP form, which, upon submission, goes to another PHP page. This validates all the input, removes backslashes etc.

My question is this: if I create a check before the PHP script processes any of the information, by checking a POST variable called something like 'uniquecode' which would be posted along with the form, would this make my form more secure?

I am using all post variables. My script is getting quite advanced and I want it to be as secure as possible, but also as simple as possible.

Comment: You haven't provided any details, it is not possible to answer your "question"

Comment: what kind of details do you need ?

Comment: what, what for and how you check. For now your question looks like "Guys, I do something. Is it cool or not?"

Comment: What do you mean by secure?  Is there a password in flux that you want to be sure is safe, or is it just that no input the user can think up should crash the server?

Comment: I am concerned that anyone could post data to the submission page, so my question is if I post a kind of access token which only the form and submission page know, and then wrap the functions on the submission page around an if statement based on the access token provided by the form, would this prevent people from posting data from other servers into the submission page?

Comment: @user1126900: no, it will not prevent anything

Comment: how would it be possible to prevent from this kind of problem? any tips appreciated :)

Comment: @user1126900: it is not possible. Anything that is possible to do with browser - can be put in the script

Comment: @zerkms: I think you're being a bit strong. You're correct that anything that can be done on a browser can be mimicked, but unique hidden inputs linked to sessions are sometimes used as an extra layer of security because it requires that potential attackers actually retrieve the form for each submission rather than just copying the fields once and then automating posts, so it makes brute-force attacks *slightly* harder. If you're relying on it in any way then you're kidding yourself, but it's not a completely useless thing to add.

Comment: I dont quite agree with downvoting this question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding additional verification fields into the HTML won't secure the form, This is because the   HTML can be manipulated by the user once rendered.

If you want to protect your form from spam, I recommend reCaptcha:
http://www.google.com/recaptcha
People on Stack Overflow will help you to integrate this if you need help.

You can also search for information about "Cross-Site scripting" (XSS) for security tips. Here is the Wikipedia article to get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Guarding against XSS is important to make sure that all the information being processed by PHP has actually come from your own site, and not somebody else's.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for this too, sorry I didn't see it at first. Very useful.

Comment: I don't have the req'd permission just yet ;)

Comment: @user1126900 worries thanks for accepting. You might want to make yourself a username :P

Answer (score 1):

I know what you're trying to do, i would use a session:

Upon loading the page and displaying the form:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['form-key'] = md5(rand(1,100000));

?>

<form method="post" action="script.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form-key']; ?>">
</form>
```

Upon submission

```
<?php
// Check this matches
session_start();
$_SESSION['form-key']==$_POST['key'];
?>
```

**Warning** If someone opens the same page in a new tab, $_SESSION['form-key'] will be reset, thus the original tab will be invalid

---

**Update** This will only prevent DIRECT posting to the form, a script could still parse the token and send it back with the submission (@zerkms)

Comment: I apologize if this was ill-formatted, curse you damn router issues

Comment: What would prevent a script from downloading the form, get the token and send form back using parsed token?

Comment: Good point, but i use this to prevent any direct posting to the form... Otherwise, there really is no practical solution

Comment: @zerkms: See my above post. Nothing is preventing it, but it can slow down brute force attacks because it requires the page be served each time the attacker wants to submit the form.

Comment: and it protects from CSRF attacks, when attacker does not have the ability to fetch-parse-post

Comment: @sakfa My iniitial reason for the logic ;)

Comment: btw: if you calculate $_SESSION['form-key'] as a combination of: application secret (known only to webapp server), user's SESSION_ID and some unique identifier for form (i.e. page name), then hash it (to prevent anyone from finding out app secret) you will get rid of a problem of resetting form-key after opening form in new tab. (form-key generation will be deterministic, and it will be safe as long as your application secret is really secret, so that nobody except the application can generate valid hashes - just keep app secret next to db pass)